# python unittest mock can't handle partially qualified name

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

If I have two files with the following contents:

`test_helper.py`:

```
class Installer:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, version):
        # Init stuff
        raise Exception('If we're here, mock didn't work')

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, tb):
        # cleanup
        pass

    def install(self):
        # Install stuff
        raise Exception('If we're here, mock didn't work')
```

And 
`test.py`:

```
import unittest
from mock import patch
from test_helper import Installer

class Deployer:
    def deploy(self):
        with Installer('foo', 'bar', 1) as installer:
            installer.install()

class DeployerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('tests.test_helper.Installer', autospec=True)
    def testInstaller(self, mock_installer):
        deployer = Deployer()
        deployer.deploy()
        mock_installer.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar', 1)
```

The code above doesn't test correctly. The mock is not applied properly:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mock-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/mock/mock.py", line 947, in assert_called_once_with
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Expected 'Installer' to be called once. Called 0 times.
```

If I make the following changes in `test.py`:

1. Change `from test_helper import Installer` to `import test_helper`, and
2. Change `with Installer('foo', 'bar', 1) as installer:` to `with test_helper.Installer('foo', 'bar', 1) as installer:`

The code then works. Why does the mock only apply when I use the fully qualified name? Is it supposed to work in the partially-qualified case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing your `Deployer` class inside `test.py`, which is calling `Installer`. This installer is what you want to mock. So, your decorator should be with respect to that.

I don't know where you are testing from exactly. But as an example, if you are running your test from the same level as `test.py`, then you can simply do this to your decorator and it should work:

```
import unittest

from dower import Installer
from mock import patch

class Deployer:
    def deploy(self):
        with Installer('foo', 'bar', 1) as installer:
            installer.install()

class DeployerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('test.Installer', autospec=True)
    def testInstaller(self, mock_installer):
        deployer = Deployer()
        deployer.deploy()
        mock_installer.assert_called_once_with('foo', 'bar', 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Note: You should not be mocking within the Installer module. You don't *care* about Installer in this case. Just that it returns your `Mock`, so you can continue testing the behaviour of your `Deployer`. Think of it that way, and you will realize why you have to mock with respect to what you are testing.

Comment: I guess this was a mix of issues. However, it was mainly to do with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060724/patch-why-wont-the-relative-patch-target-name-work That was what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: @Srikanth Read deeply https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch (3 or 4 times if you need) then accept this answer because is the correct one.